# How to get http response header in npapi plugin

Tags: c, linux, http, browser, npapi

i am new to plugin development. I was told to use Firebreath, for developing npapi plugins, and it turned out to be very easy. Now, i wish to access the http response header of the response passed on to plugin. But i couldn't figure out a way as their is scarce doc available for firebreath. In NPAPI tutorials, they use npstream, but i can't figure out how to use this structure in firebreath. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

```
void tPlugin::handleUnsolicitedStream(FB::BrowserStreamRequest& req)
{ 
 const FB::PluginEventSinkPtr sinkPtr;
 req.setEventSink(sinkPtr);
 responseHeaders = req.headers;
 FB::HeaderMap::const_iterator it = responseHeaders.begin();
 str = (*it).first + " : " + (*it).second;                   // str is a class variable
 FB::DOM::WindowPtr window = m_host->getDOMWindow();
 window->alert(str);
 str = "hello";
 window->alert(fname);
}
```

None of the alert box appears!

```
void tPlugin::onPluginReady()
{
   FB::DOM::WindowPtr window = m_host->getDOMWindow();
   window->alert(str);
}
```

An empty alert box appears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [source](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/BrowserStreamRequest.h) for the BrowserStreamRequest object that you are using, or even better if you read the source for where it is created, you will find that there is a headers variable on the object.

```
FB::HeaderMap headers;
```

FB::HeaderMap, of course, is defined in [SimpleStreamHelper.h](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/SimpleStreamHelper.h):

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, std::string> HeaderMap;
```

And, to clarify, there is plenty of documentation for FireBreath; just not a lot for this particular feature, which has only been in the tree for about a month.

**Edit:** From past conversations I'm pretty sure you're already handling this, but the stream created by the browser is given to you with the BrowserStreamRequest object passed into the [handleUnsolicitedStream](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/PluginCore.h#L338) method on your plugin object; this method isn't overridden by your plugin by default in the fbgen template, but you can add it.

Comment: You ask for the location of the headers that come from the response; they are put into the BrowserStreamRequest object which is created apon creation of the stream (in NPP_NewStream)

Comment: This is where I'm confused, because from past conversations with you I thought you were already handling unsolicited streams, but I have updated my answer to include that info.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand my answer; I'm not talking about when you create an http request.  I'm talking about the case where the browser receives a response containing a mime-type and the plugin is invoked.  When you want the headers of that same response, the handleUnsolicitedStream method is called.  There is a public property of type FB::HeaderMap on that FB::BrowserStreamRequest object that has the headers that you are looking for in it. it isn't a method! it's just a public property.  Go look at the code. Also try a debugger.  I don't know how else I can explain the same thing.

Comment: Sorry.  You're welcome to attach a debugger and try to verify this, but most likely if that's the case then the browser simply isn't providing any header information.

Comment: If you'll follow the thread, you'll see the jira ticket referenced is http://jira.firebreath.org/browse/FIREBREATH-210 which is resolved. (yes, it is fixed)

Comment: response headers are doing fine, can i access request header which invoked the response header?

Comment: There is no way that I know of to access the request header, no